# How to save a file path at database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, uploadify

i'm doing a music upload to my application, using the uploadify plugin, the upload are working, but, when i'll save the path reference (where the music are saved on my project), i'm getting null value, anyone knows how can I do this?

**Upload Method at MusicController**

```
public ActionResult Upload()
{
    var file = Request.Files["Filedata"];
    string savePath = Server.MapPath(@"~\mp3\" + file.FileName);
    file.SaveAs(savePath);
    return Content(Url.Content(@"~\mp3\" + file.FileName));
}
```

**Create Method at MusicController**

```
  public ActionResult Create(Musica musica)
        {
            MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
            int userId = Int32.Parse(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString());
            string userName = user.UserName;

            musica.UserId = userId;
            musica.NomeArtista = userName;

            if (musica.isFree)
            {

                musica.Preco = 0;
            }

            //Here I try to take the path value
            musica.path = Upload().ToString();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Musicas.Add(musica);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.GeneroId = new SelectList(db.Generos, "GeneroId", "Nome", musica.GeneroId);
            return View(musica);
        }
```

On this case, I only want to save in my database, this information:

```
~\mp3\MusicExample.mp3
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Are you just trying to save this `~\mp3\MusicExample.mps` as a `varchar` field in the database, or are you trying to do a [BLOB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894716/how-to-save-image-as-varbinay-in-sql-server-2008r2/23899574#23899574)?

Comment: It looks like you're calling the `Upload` controller action in your `Create` action. That doesn't make any sense. If the `Upload` method's only use is to save the file, (i.e. it's not an action at all) it should return a `string` or something like that, not an `ActionResult`.

Comment: @alykins As a varchar!

Comment: @DaveZych I'm using this tutorial to do the upload http://jayendraka.wordpress.com/2013/10/18/use-uploadify-controls-with-asp-net-mvc4/, On this tutorial, he use the ActionResult on method created.

Comment: But an action result is not a string. Does ActionResult object have properties maybe?

Comment: @alkins one thing that I tried to do is: create the reference of "Musica" model on begin of controller, and on method Upload, use that: `musicModelReference.path = @"~/mp3/"+file.FileName;`, and on create method use this `musica.path = musicModelReference.path`, it's not work too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** So the upload method you're using is asynchronous, and it uploads the file and returns the file path back to the page. Change the upload method to return the file path you want, capture it in the jQuery and create a control that holds the information after it's uploaded:

Your upload method should be this:

```
public ActionResult Upload()
{
    var file = Request.Files["Filedata"];
    string savePath = Server.MapPath(@"~\mp3\" + file.FileName);
    file.SaveAs(savePath);
    return Content(@"~\mp3\" + file.FileName);
}
```

Somwhere in your view, add a control for the `path` property:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.path, new { id = "path"})
```

In the javascript, capture the return value and set it inside the new textbox for the `path` property in musica:

```
'onUploadSuccess': function (file, data, response) {
                $("#path").val(data);
            }
```

In the create method, remove the code to call `Upload`:

```
//Stuff above here
if (musica.isFree)
{
    musica.Preco = 0;
}

//Here I try to take the path value
//musica.path = Upload().ToString();

if (ModelState.IsValid)
//stuff below here
```

Now, when you click on the create button, it should automatically set the path property to the file path, and it should just work

Comment: It's not working, the error is displayed: "Unrecognized escape sequence" is displayed at fileName line.

Comment: @PedroHenrique updated. Add another `\` to escape the backslash.

Comment: @DaveZich Not working yet, i think that is because when I call the `musica.path = upload()` the application run the method again and the nullpointerException is displayed

Comment: I think that should be added the reference of model on upload method like: `musicReference.path = "~\\mp3\\"+file.FileName;` and in the create method, must be called that musicReference as: `musica.path = musicReference.path;` What do you think?

Comment: Do you have separate upload and create actions? Meaning, the user clicks a button to upload, then after the page reloads they click another button for create? There's not enough information here to help more than I have.

Comment: They are on the same view, I'll put the view code on pastebin, link: http://pastebin.com/3Sq3JPMF

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your view/jquery/etc. It should work now.

Comment: Oh, thank you guy, now it's working, thanks for your help! Now I need to implement the download method, could you recommend some article to me?