# Store Path File in Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, file

I want to know to use files in my ASP.NET MVC App.
I need to store the path of the file in the database
(SQL Server), but where do I have to save the file 
(not the path)? Do I have to store them in the IIS?
I'm really confused. A good reference will be awesome.

Hope you can help me.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: IIS is NOT a file system. You need to store the files on a server somewhere, preferably that will be the same path that you store in sql.

Comment: you can store it in SQL server itself (small number of files, relatively small file size), or store the path in SQL and file in File System.

Comment: Why don't you store it to a blob? I mean the whole contents of the file ... It has some advantages, e.g. when creating a backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps this can help you:

[How to save a file path at database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897132/how-to-save-a-file-path-at-database)
if not, could you be more clear on what you want?
and maby some (pseudo)code might help to clearify what you mean.

Comment: I'm doing an app like dropbox. Is it possible to store the files in the same project or I need to use a web server?. What server do I have to use?

Comment: Yes it is possible to save files inside the project folder of you application. You'll need to set the rights correctly (read & write). This approach is usually not the common way. Best practice is to have a different file server or network share inside your network. This way your project folder doesn't get cluttered with uploaded data.